# execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.NullPointerException:

Tags: apex, trigger, exception, null-pointer

Attempt to de-reference a null object ()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it would be as simple as wrapping all the acc ifs inside a bigger if that checks if acc is null or not, for example your for would be something like...

```
for (sm1e__smWork_Order__c o: WOList) {
    sm1e__smEquipment__c at = ObjMap.get(o.sm1e__Equipment__c);
    Account acc = AccountMap.get(o.sm1e__Account__c);
    if (acc != null) {
        if (acc.Site_Check_in_Procedures__c != Null) {
            o.Site_Instructions__c = acc.Site_Check_in_Procedures__c; }
        if (acc.Gate_Combo_Codes__c != Null) {
            o.Gate_Combo_Codes__c = acc.Gate_Combo_Codes__c; }
        if (acc.Site_Access__c != Null) {
            o.Site_Access__c = acc.Site_Access__c; }
        if (acc.Site_Name__c != Null) {
            o.Site_Name__c = acc.Site_Name__c; }
        if(acc.Site_Phone__c != Null) {
            o.Site_Phone__c = acc.Site_Phone__c; }
        if (acc.System_Overview__c != Null) {
            o.System_Overview__c = acc.System_Overview__c; }
        if (acc.Site_Check_in_Procedures__c != Null) {
            o.Site_Check_in_Procedures__c = acc.Site_Check_in_Procedures__c; }
        if (acc.System_Overview__c != Null) {
            o.System_Overview__c = acc.System_Overview__c; }
        if (acc.Site_Scheduling_Process__c != Null) {
            o.Site_Scheduling_Process__c = acc.Site_Scheduling_Process__c; }
        if (acc.Roof_Access__c != Null) {
            o.Roof_Access__c = acc.Roof_Access__c; }
        if (acc.Employee_Phone_Number__c != Null) {
            o.Employee_Phone_Number__c= acc.Employee_Phone_Number__c; }
    }

    if (at.Default_Failure_Class__c != Null) {
        o.sm1e__Failure_Class__c = at.Default_Failure_Class__c; }
    if (at.sm1e__Service_Region__c != Null) {
        o.sm1e__Service_Region__c = at.sm1e__Service_Region__c; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed that part. It doesnot throw the exception anymore.

Comment: Can someone help me with validation? I am getting this error during validation.
https://ibb.co/ka9Cfw

Comment: Here is the preventWOdel class and test class.

https://ibb.co/dssyLw

Comment: I guess it is because of https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/197822/trigger-deployment-error-execution-of-beforeinsert-caused-by-system-nullpointe. The same thing, inside the for, group the assignations that have the `acc.` on the right side and put them inside an `if (acc != null){}` block

Comment: I think i found the solution. We did the null check for acc. but not for at. so now i did it for both and validation was successful.